# How can I see the absolute timestamp of a discussion comment in VSTS?

Tags: azure-devops

In the "Discussion" area of a VSTS task item, the timestamps are shown as the relative ones (eg. "*commented 7 days ago*") rather than the absolute ones (i.e. the exact date and time). VSTS does not a preference setting to display the absolute timestamp.

How can I easily know the absolute timestamp (for example, July 05, 2018, 9:12:36 am) of a comment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you hover the mouse over the relative timestamp, the absolute one is shown as a tooltip. [See screenshot here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6QJeh.png)